# "At what point does another year of age reduce the probability of smoking?"

Tags: statistics, regression, economics

Say I have something like:

$$pSmoke = .656 - .069log(cigprice)+.012log(income)-.029educ + .02age - .00026age^2 - .101restaurn - .026white$$

where $pSmoke$ is the probability of smoking and $age$ is the person's age in years. This is part of a larger model but I just have this part for simplicity.

$\log(cigprice)$ is the logarithm of cigarette prices.

$\log(income)$ is the logarithm of the income of the individual.

$educ$ is the years of education.

$restaurn$ is a binary variable (1 for no smoking in restaurants. 0 otherwise).

$white$ is 1 if the respondent is white (I assume ethnicity)

---

The question asks, at what age does another year of age reduce the probability of smoking?

It seems the correct answer is to compute the derivative with respect to age and set it equal to 0. This gets you age = 38.46

What I did was set the given equation equal to 0. This gets you about 77. Is this incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

The important piece of language here is "*another* year of age." That is, when does adding a new year of age cause the probability of smoking to decline, rather than increase? This says nothing about the absolute probability of smoking, but rather the change in probability with respect to another year, that is, the derivative of $pSmoking$ with respect to $age$. So indeed the correct approach is to differentiate and set to zero.

(I would note that to fully believe your answer, you need to also show that this is a max of $pSmoking$, rather than a minmum or a nonextermal critical point.)

Setting the equation equal to zero finds you not the point where a new year causes probability to decline, but rather the age where the probability of smoking hits *zero.* This is a statement about the actual probability, not the effect of changing age on the probability.

Comment: That's what I had believed when I realized I had done this incorrectly. I appreciate the confirmation. However, if this point does, in fact, demonstrate a change (I.e. graphing this and showing that probability decreases after age 77) then is it a valid claim?

Comment: On further thought. The problem asks when another year of smoking DECREASES the probability of smoking. The derivative finds the max of the slope (the max probability of smoking as a function of age). But the next year this equation still doesn't reduce the probability of smoking. I should have included every part of the model. One second.

Comment: So now with this model. At age 38,39,40 etc. the probability of smoking is still positive. It's progressively less positive but it doesn't decrease the probability of smoking until age ~77. Thoughts?

Comment: @Nicklovn It´s not true that it doesn´t decrease or increases until age of $\sim 77.$ It increases until the age of $38.462$

Comment: Sorry I'm still not seeing it as you are. The question is, "at what point does another year of age reduce the probability of smoking?" In the scope of the whole equation, at age 38.462, it seems your probability of smoking is still increased. I see that the slope is zero but what I don't see is why it reduces the probability of smoking. If you're 39, the equation suggests that the probability of smoking increases substantially. But as you age until 77 the magnitude decreases.

Comment: That's where I'm failing to connect between what you're saying and what I'm starting to see. Edit: I think I'm just confused on the wording of this problem.

Comment: The reason for the confusion is understanding the problem differently I think. At 38.46 you are achieving the maximal probability of smoking as a function of age. Afterwards, the probability decreases. But the equation shows that at a particular age your probability of smoking will be reduced as a function of age. I.e., being 77+ leads you to be less likely to smoke.

Comment: @Nicklovn After $a=76.92$ the quadratic function becomes negative. This cannot interpreted. But if we just focus on the factor age we can say the probability for smoking decreases between age $38.46$ and age $76.92$